# Running MS Paint with Wine and get "Failed to create empty document"

Tags: wine, windows-7, winetricks

So a while back I mannaged to follow a few rabbit holes to get MS Paint running-ish with Wine on Ubuntu 20.04 (it's been a while so I don't know what sources and other stuff I installed to get here)

When I run `wine ~/Desktop/programs/mspaint.exe` in a console the MS Paint window looks like this:

[image]

And when I exit out of the window the console gives me a few different types of error messages each time I run the command, but most of the time it's just
`0114:err:ole:start_rpcss Failed to start RpcSs service 0114:err:ole:CoReleaseMarshalData StdMarshal ReleaseMarshalData failed with error 0x8001011d`
but it's ONLY after I exit the MS Paint window.
Anyone know how I can get it to launch like it should?
(The MS Paint version was made for windows 7)

Comment: mspaint Win7 has never worked on wine: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=373 . Try the XP version. The Win7 version's error comes from mfc42u.dll and likely needs code fixes. Also consider drawing programs made for Linux such as GIMP and Krita

Comment: I'd rather do some code fixes than use a different Linux based program because I'm just so fluent with MS Paint. And most of the features from Windows 7 MS Paint aren't in other programs.

Comment: You can use the Windows XP version: https://archive.org/details/MSPaintWinXP . For the code fixes, I meant that for MS Office I had to spend 2 weeks writing code at https://gitlab.winehq.org/wine/wine and I only got the welcome screen working. Unless there is a major feature you need from the Win7 version, I don't know of anyone who is working on this